# Identifying this coax connector?

Tags: audio, connector, cables

Circular 1-pin coax connector. Trying to identify so I can buy a new socket for it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's not a bayonet. A bayonet would have a twist to lock, as far as I know. It's just a co-axial connector. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount

Comment: Why do you need the female? Cable mount, panel mount, or PCB mount? What problem do you need to solve?

Answer (score 4):

That is a [Belling Lee aerial coax connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling-Lee_connector).

The female jacks for it are hard to find. For example: https://octopart.com/l1465%2Frpcs-belling+lee-7477530